# How check date 20140211 in php?

Tags: csv, strtotime, strftime

When the import csv with the field as '20150331', we will import 2015/03/31 00:00:00 as its expire date.
When the import csv omit the field we will import current time + 365 days as the expire date?

Comment: It's not very clear what your problem is. Can you please provide more information and explain your question or problem in more detail please?

Comment: it's alreaed fix with my friend, i want to put date in my csv row in column date it will put only '20140219' with condition 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'. 
thx for reply.

Comment: It would be good to answer your own question in that case.